# Values of Hammett Acidity function for differing concentrations of H2SO4?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am styling the effect of the concentration of different catalysts on the hydrolysis of sucrose to study it's reaction mechanism. I will be using the Hammett-Zucker hypothesis to find the molecularity of the reaction but I am unable to find a H0 value for H2SO4 anywhere. Is there some source I am missing or can I calculate it?

Comment: More like a chart for H0 value for H2SO4 solutions. For pure it's about -12, but you need diluted - it's -1 for 20% for example.

Comment: How did you know it is -1 for 20%? Do you have some table that I can refer to?

Comment: Only got few example values, but I'm pretty sure more data could be found on internet.